# how to use datetime variable in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

i'm trying to use a variable that i get it from an html form
here is the html code

```
<input type="date" name="begin_date">
<input type="date" name="end_date">
```

and i will enter something like this 2015-6-20 00:00:00 in the text fields.
then i want to use those variables in mysql where clause like below:

```
->where('o.invoice_date >= $begin_date AND o.invoice_date < $end_date');
```

but somehow it doesn't work... 
when i do it like

```
->where('o.invoice_date >= "2015-6-20 00:00:00" AND o.invoice_date < "2015-6-20 00:00:00"');
```

it works fine but not with variables.. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

replace single quotes with double

not

```
->where('o.invoice_date >= $begin_date AND o.invoice_date < $end_date');
```

but

```
->where("o.invoice_date >= $begin_date AND o.invoice_date < $end_date");
```

also `$begin_date` should be defined like `$begin_date = $_POST['begin_date']`

`$end_date` in same manner

Comment: thanks so much .. it's working ;)